# post a dictionary to web service from objective - c

Tags: post, dictionary

My web service api (POST) has a parameter that takes a dictionary object like this

```
void MyMethod (Dictionary<string, List<string>> myDictionaryParam);
```

Basically, the keys are strings and the values are an array of strings.

How do i send this data from Objective C.

So far, i have tried the following.

```
NSMutableDictionary* dataDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dataDictionary setObject:personIds forKey:"firstKey"];
    [dataDictionary setObject:personIds forKey:@"secondKey"];

    NSDictionary* dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:dataDictionary, @"myDictionaryParam", nil];


    NSError* seralizationError;
    NSData* data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&seralizationError];
```

The API gets the dictionary, but the dictionary has 0 key/value pairs.

Don't worry about how to post json data..I got that part covered. I am interested in knowing how to post an actual dictionary object from Objective C

Comment: Don't understand your comments - you are not posting a dictionary, you are posting json. So what does this mean: "how to post an actual dictionary object"? And where are you passing the dictionary to the API?  Your code shows a dictionary, which then gets converted to NSData, then you do nothing with either. Are you asking how to pass a dictionary to MyMethod without its contents being 0? If so then show that code not something else. As it stands, your question is very confusing.

Comment: I understand you don't post a dictionary. You post JSON data. My question is how to post JSON data that will have a dictionary object that the server can understand

Comment: Your NSData contains the JSON, you post that using NSURLSession as you have indicated you already know how to do.The NSData contains the Json that contains the contents of the dictionary.  Provided your dictionary keys are as the server is expecting and the server is expecting a dictionary embedded within the jason then the server will understand it.

Comment: Yup. The problem however was that on the server i get 0 key/value pairs for the dictionary. i think you understood my problem, but for others sake, look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17373452/call-a-webmethod-passing-dictionarystring-string-as-parameter  question. I want to do exactly the same from objective c

Comment: Well have you confirmed that the data variable actually contains something? You can NSLog [data description] as a string. Have you checked if seralizationError is nil, if not why not? In other words what have you done to confirm you are sending some json content rather than just assuming you are.

Comment: Yes. I confirmed serialzationError is nil and I get this JSON data.........{
    "myDictionaryParam": {
        "firstKey": [
            "0B976E63-526C-4C5E-BAD9-AB2C63C3BF93",
            "23DCD0B0-9E3A-4CDB-AFFC-F8A356186E23",
            "114C2A4A-F742-46AF-A5F9-4B9F210A8FBC"
        ],
        "secondKey": [
            "0B976E63-526C-4C5E-BAD9-AB2C63C3BF93",
            "23DCD0B0-9E3A-4CDB-AFFC-F8A356186E23",
            "114C2A4A-F742-46AF-A5F9-4B9F210A8FBC"
        ]
    }
}

Comment: Then you need to show the code where you are sending the data to the server. There's no problem with the code you've posted.  You can also use http://requestb.in and check sending the data to a bin to confirm you are actually sending something.